# Do we need to package Newtonsoft JSON.Net dll file along with main application in order to make it work in non-visual studio systems?

Tags: c#, json, dll, .net-4.5, visual-studio-2013

I have a DLL project that will be used by WinForms application. I have used NewtonSoft JSON.NET for JSON deserialization.

```
Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Newtonsoft.Json.xml
```

Now, My application works fine on a system that has Visual Studio.NET Installed, but does not load on system which do not have VS.NET.
My Target version is .NET 4.5 and I have installed the below file in test machine that does not have VS.NET.

```
dotnetfx45_full_x86_x64.exe
```

The Test machine returns the following error.

```
Plugin failed to initialize: Could not load managed bridge library.
```

Do I need to include all the references that I have added to my solution?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I''ve the same question. How do I install the Newtonsoft.Json.dll on the target machine. Should this go in GAC ? The problem is my App dll goes in GAC as well.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a matter of whether you've got VS.NET installed - it's a matter of whether you've got Json.NET in the right place. It's a third party library that you depend on, so you should ship it with your app. Personally I would copy it alongside your application, rather than installing it in the GAC, but that's a slightly different choice.

Now, it's not clear that the exception is *actually* due to Json.NET being missing in the first place. It doesn't *sound* like a particularly JSON-related error. Assuming it's actually a .NET exception, you should look at the *full* stack trace - there may well be a nested exception which gives more information.

As a general answer though: yes, if you use any libraries which aren't part of .NET itself, you need to include them with your application.

Comment: Thank You @Jon Skeet, I have included both the `Newtonsoft.Json.dll`
`Newtonsoft.Json.xml` files along with my application but still get that error. Problem is, I cannot get the stack trace as it is a third party app. So, do I need to include the following files(whatever .net reference I have used) too along with my application?
`System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll`
`System.Web.Http.dll`

Comment: @aceventura: No, you don't need to include those DLLs as they're part of .NET - but it sounds like you need to get more diagnostic information about the application. We don't really have enough information to help you further (we know pretty much nothing about the application) but it sounds like you should quite possibly get in touch with the authors.

Comment: Thanks again @Jon Skeet. Shall check with the 3rd party client related to what additional files they need. **Merry Christmas!!!**

Comment: @aceventura: Yes, you should definitely do that. It will very much depend on the application.